How do I use a standalone angular component in a module?
According to the docs, this should be easy peasy, so I'm obviously missing something vital. I have a minimal test project in preparation for possibly migrating a rather large angular application to the standalone practice. But the migration will need to in progress for a while and still work with the old code.
In my test project I have a standalone bootstrapped angular 17 app. It has one module (old style) and one standalone component. I have managed to include the module in the standalone root app component. But I am not able to use a standalone component in the module. The docs says all I have to do is import the component in the module, but that does not seem to work, or I am doing it wrong somehow.
Here is a similar test project that does not compile.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qgscg9?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest-module%2Ftest-module.module.ts
The TestStandaloneComponent is imported in the module TestModuleModule, but the selector is still not recognised.
I've tried importing it in the main.ts:
imports: [RouterModule, TestModuleModule, TestStandaloneComponent]

but that has no effect.
(I did have a lot of trouble understanding how to even include the module in the app, so I'm not entirely sure that is correctly done either, but since that part compiles, I guess it's fine. )
What am I missing?

You stackblitz looks like work. I made ng build and ng build --prod and generate the bundles. has you "re-start" the server (Ctrl+C and then ng serve) after adding the component to the Module?

Check this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dxj68d

Oh for effs sake! I just turned it off and restarted with ng serve and now it compiles. AAARRRGGGHH :D  Thanks!

Well, that was a few hours I'll never get back. I restarted the app and now it compiles... DOH!
